# ASP.net make Buttons set GridView Visible property to True or False

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have an ASP.net web page that has 2 gridviews.  I have 2 buttons where I want to be able to click one to make 1 gridview visible and the other hidden, and the other button to make the first gridview hidden and the 2nd gridview visible.  When I click either of them nothing happens.  I've played around with the gridview visible settings w/ no luck.I'm sure its simple.  Thanks for looking! Some code is below:

The 2 Gridviews:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridShowUsers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="user_id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AllowPaging="True">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="user_id" HeaderText="User ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="user_id" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="user_name" HeaderText="Username" SortExpression="user_name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="user_password" HeaderText="Password" SortExpression="user_password" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="user_securitylevel" HeaderText="Security Level" SortExpression="user_securitylevel" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

<asp:GridView ID="gridOrders" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ordr_id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" EmptyDataText="There are no Orders to Display" AllowPaging="True">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" ShowSelectButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ordr_id" HeaderText="ordr_id" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ordr_id" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ordr_date" HeaderText="ordr_date" SortExpression="ordr_date" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ordr_fname" HeaderText="ordr_fname" SortExpression="ordr_fname" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ordr_lname" HeaderText="ordr_lname" SortExpression="ordr_lname" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ordr_streetaddress" HeaderText="ordr_streetaddress" SortExpression="ordr_streetaddress" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ordr_city" HeaderText="ordr_city" SortExpression="ordr_city" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ordr_state" HeaderText="ordr_state" SortExpression="ordr_state" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ordr_zipcode" HeaderText="ordr_zipcode" SortExpression="ordr_zipcode" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Code behind for the buttons:

```
protected void btnShowUsers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gridShowUsers.Visible = true;
    gridOrders.Visible = false;
}

protected void btnShowOrders_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gridShowUsers.Visible = false;
    gridOrders.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: I do not see btnShowUsers and btnShowOrders in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your code SHOULD work, but maybe something is wrong with the overall context. Please also provide the code of your buttons, and maybe the full page code - or is this stuff maybe in UpdatePanels?

---

Anyway, does it have to happen via a postback, meaning in the c#-code? Otherwise I would propose you use client side solutions, f.e. jQuery or javascript.

In jQuery you could do it like this (assuming your button IDs):

```
$("#btnShowUsers").on("click", function(){
  $("#gridShowUsers").show();
  $("#gridOrders").hide();
});

$("#btnShowOrders").on("click", function(){
  $("#gridShowUsers").hide();
  $("#gridOrders").show();
});
```

This also enables you to do fancy stuff like animations (try .hide(500)) or use functions like toggle(), and it doesn't cause a postback and therefore doesn't reload the whole page.

Don't forget to add the lates stable jQuery library to your asp.net -section (https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```